# How can I catch an exception raised inside of a catch clause, If the finally clause corresponding to the catch clause contains a return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

Suppose that:

- `TEF` is a `try-except-finally` block.
- an exception is raised from within the `try` clause of `TEF`
- The finally clause, `F` of block `T` contains a return statement
- `TEF` contains an except clause `E`
- an exception `e` is raised inside of `E`
- How can we catch `e` from outside of clause `F` and outside of clause `E`?

---

If that was confusing, then some code is shown below:

```
def e():
    out = "hello world"
    try:
        raise ValueError("my name is Sarah")
    except BaseException as exc:

        # HOW DO I CATCH THE FIRST OF THE FOLLOWING
        # exceptions from outside of this, current,
        # except clause?

        raise ValueError("secret info it would be good to know")
        raise AttributeError
        raise type("Hell", (Exception,), dict())()
        [0, 1, 2][99999]

        class AnythingYouCanThinkOf(Exception):
            pass

        raise AnythingYouCanThinkOf

        out = "definitely not `hello world`"
    finally:
        return out

print(e())
print("No error!!! wowza!")
```

The code above prints:

```
hello world
No error!!! wowza!
```

If we comment out the line `out = "hello world"` then we get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out' referenced before assignment`. However, I am still not sure how to recover `ValueError("secret info it would be good to know")`

Also, if you put almost the same code outside of the function `e`, you get very different results. Why?

```
if True:
    out = "hello world"
    try:
        raise ValueError("my name is Bob")
    except BaseException as exc:

        # HOW DO I CATCH THE FIRST OF THE FOLLOWING
        # exceptions from outside of this, current,
        # except clause?

        raise ValueError("what is this madness?")

        class AnythingYouCanThinkOf(Exception):
            pass

        raise AnythingYouCanThinkOf

        out = "definitely not `hello world`"
    finally:
        print(out)
```

The above results in unhandled exception `ValueError: what is this madness?` before, we got `No error!!! wowza!`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is the scenario: if `e()` has an exception in the try block, raise an error, if not return `out`? If so, you only need to move `return out` outside the `finally` block

Comment: Why would you put a `return` in a `finally` block unless you wanted to suppress exceptions?